# InDesign 'find object format' by width and change, 'cannot find match'

Tags: adobe-indesign, object-styles

Basically I want to find objects that are 423 pixels wide and change them. Is this possible? It seems like it should be pretty straight forward!

I've been trying with 'text frame general options' but I think that is more for columns and their widths.

Answer (score 1):

Nope you can't. Only way to target items based on geometrical properties is to script that search.